# Can't insert values into table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert values from a register form to the database but I keep getting the message 'User Registration Failed', and I don't know why.

```
<?php
include("home.html");
require('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($result)
    {
        $smsg = "User Created Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why; check for errors.

Comment: print you query to check mysql error.

Comment: `else
    {
        echo "error happen".mysqli_error($connection);
    }`. Also you are open to `SQL Injection`. Check for `prepared statement` to prevent  `SQL Injection`

Comment: `echo $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.